# numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'batch'

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, scikit-learn, image-classification

I am building an image classifier using cnn using the following code-
[image: code]

I am getting this error, despite making several changes-
[image: output]

Kindly help me fix this error.

Comment: The error message simply means that an numpy ndarray object does not have a function called batch. If you want some further help, please could you explain what you are trying to do in this part of the code, so people can suggest ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

`.batch()` method is usually applying to objects of `tf.data.Dataset` type. In your case applying this method is non needed and surely cannot be done because your data has `ndarray` type.

Just remove `.batch()` from your code and specify batch_size arg in 'fit()' method if it is needed.